# How to catch the error if module cannot be found?

Tags: reactjs

I want to import a file that exports an array of strings. The file is generated dynamically, so if it does not exist I want to import an default file. How can I avoid the error "File not found" and import the default array instead?

file ColorsDefault.jsx

```
export const ColorsDefault = ["blue", "red", "green"]
```

index,jsx

```
import Colors from "./Colors/ColorsDynamic"               // Might not exist
import ColorsDefault from "./Colors/ColorsDefault"

export const colors = Colors || ColorsDefault
```

Comment: Would it be possible to generate an export for empty values as empty array or null?

Comment: @HMR the path to the file and its name are dynamically build by webpack depending on the .env